# Blocking requests from specific IPs using IIS Rewrite module

Tags: iis, blocking

I'm trying to block a range of IP that is sending tons of spam to my blog. I can't use the solution described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/86755/18423) because it's a shared hosting and I can't change anything to the server configuration. I only have access to a few options in Remote IIS.

I see that the URL Rewrite module has an option to block requests, so I tried to use it. My rule is as follows in `web.config`:

```
            <rule name="BlockSpam" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="10\.0\.146\.23[0-9]" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" />
            </rule>
```

Unfortunately, if I put it at the end of the rewrite rules, it doesn't seem to block anything... and if I put it at the start of the list, it blocks everything! It looks like the condition isn't taken into account.

In the UI, the `stopProcessing` option is not visible and is `true` by default. Changing it to `false` in `web.config` doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm not sure what to do now... any ideas?

Comment: Can you stop them in programming level?

Comment: I guess I could, but I'd rather not. It's a Wordpress blog, and I'm not really comfortable in messing with WP code...

Answer (score 6):

**#1 WP Plug-in**

Wordpress, check out the follow, you may or may not need a plug-in

1. [Read this link](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/01/27/best-of-wordpress-anti-spam-plugins-and-why-you-need-none-to-fight-spam/) discuss various WP anti-spam plugin and *tuning WP setting* so you don't need plugin.
2. [Top 10 WP Anti-spam plugin](http://www.net-security.org/article.php?id=987)
3. [Wordpress plugin page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=anti-spam)

Since you do have control over the web server, installing plugin should be no problem.

**#2 IIS Web.config**

IP base blocking can be done with IIS Web.config, following is example for allowing all but blocking specific IPs

```
<security>
   <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    <!-- this line allows everybody, except those listed below -->            
       <clear/>     <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->                
       <add ipAddress="83.116.19.53"/>     <!-- blocks the specific IP of 83.116.19.53  -->                
       <add ipAddress="83.116.119.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/>     <!--blocks network 83.116.119.0 to 83.116.119.255-->                
       <add ipAddress="83.116.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>     <!--blocks network 83.116.0.0 to 83.116.255.255-->                
       <add ipAddress="83.0.0.0" subnetMask="255.0.0.0"/>     <!--blocks entire /8 network of 83.0.0.0 to 83.255.255.255-->                
   </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

More info in this [link](http://www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-ip-address-restriction.aspx).

**#3 IIS Web.config rewrite**

Found following [here](https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1591/windows-ip-restrictions-via-url-rewrite-in-windows-2008.aspx), maybe you can try it.

```
<!-- Heading for the XML File -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <!-- This is where the rules start, this one will block EVERYTHING on your site with the <match url=".*" /> -->
            <rules>
                <rule name="Blocked Users" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <!-- This will just go to the 'Bad Ips' rewriteMap below and compare it to the REMOTE_ADDR which is the requesting IP -->
                        <add input="{Bad Ips:{REMOTE_ADDR}}" pattern="1" />
                    </conditions>
                    <!-- Actions can be Custom Rewrite, Redirect, or Just Abort Request, uncomment examples as needed -->
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
                    <!-- This one will rewrite url to specified file
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="error.html" appendQueryString="false" /> -->
                    <!-- This on will redirect to another site
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.google.com" appendQueryString="false" /> -->
                    <!-- This one will just Abort
                    <action type="AbortRequest" /> -->
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <!-- This rewrite Map is where you choose your blocked IP's, values with 1 are blocked, all others are ignored, simple add your keys -->
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="Bad Ips">
                    <!-- This one will use wildcards -->
                    <add key="108.166.*.*" value="1" />
                    <!-- This one wil use static IP -->
                    <add key="12.13.15.16" value="1" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to detect these spams at Wordpress level. I already use Akismet, and I blacklisted the IPs in WP, but the volume of these spams is such that the dashboard becomes unusable until I delete them. I just want to stop answering requests from these addresses

Comment: I updated the answer with Web.config IP base blocking.

Comment: Thanks, but this is assuming that the IP restriction role is installed. Unfortunately it's not the case, and since it's a shared hosting I can't install it. The URL Rewrite module seems to be my only option.

Comment: Added a rewrite method found in web.

Comment: This looks promising, but it doesn't seem to have any effect... thanks anyway.